# Clone a repository and checkout branch

Tags: git, github

I have cloned a private repository locally that has 3 branches - master, dev and staging.  When it is cloned I am in the master branch.  When I list branches:

```
git branch -a
```

I see all the branches.  When I run:

```
git checkout dev
```

nothing happens and I am still in the master branch.  I have tried to pull and fetch to get the other branches with no luck.  I can't figure out how to switch to any of the other branches.

Comment: Do you get an error when you try to checkout?

Comment: No.  Nothing happens.

Comment: How do you know you're still in `master`?

Comment: Using git branch shows what branch I am using

Comment: I had found this and it works.  Can anyone tell me why?  Do I need to use this command whenever I clone a repository?

git branch -r | grep -v '\->' | while read remote; do git branch --track "${remote#origin/}" "$remote"; done

Comment: When you say *nothing happens*, you mean you get a command prompt back as if it succeeded, but Git did not create, then switch to, branch `dev`? That's odd. This should not be Git-version-dependent, but: what version of Git are you using? Also, is there a file or directory named `dev` in the repository, that shows up in your `master` checkout?

Comment: Update: actually, this probably *is* version dependent; see answer below.

Comment: @torek - Yes, I get a command prompt and I am still on the master branch.  When I run git branch -a I see all the branches but only master is available.  I can't seem to checkout any other branch.  There are 3 branches in the repository and all of them have files.  That being said, if I start over and clone the repository and then run -----* git branch -r | grep -v '\->' | while read remote; do git branch --track "${remote#origin/}" "$remote"; done  -------  That seemed to fix my problem.  Although I don't know why and was looking for an explanation.

Comment: See my answer for my guess. You can avoid the problem using `git checkout --track origin/dev` (or upgrade Git to a later version so that it doesn't just do inexplicable things).

Comment: @torek I can confirm that I am using 2.17.2 (Apple Git-113) so it is an older version.  Do I need to follow what you have done or is the command I used just as effective as well?  The command I ran seems to have worked, I just don't know why.  Also, what do I do to upgrade Git to avoid this altogether?

Comment: The method you used (`git branch --track dev origin/dev`) will have created `dev` with `origin/dev` set as its upstream, which is all the convenience "do what I mean" mode of `git checkout` does. The issue with older versions of Git is that if there is a *file or directory* with the *same name* as the name of the branch you want to create or check out, it's not clear to Git whether you mean the *file or directory* or the *branch*.

Comment: Most people on Macs seem to use `brew` to install newer versions of software these days. That's what I have on mine (but I haven't updated that Mac since 2.20.1).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a guess, but I've reproduced the behavior:

```
sh-3.2$ mkdir txx
sh-3.2$ cd txx
sh-3.2$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
sh-3.2$ echo test branch name thing > README.md
sh-3.2$ git add README.md
sh-3.2$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) 7dc0be2] initial
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README.md
sh-3.2$ echo this is a file named dev > dev
sh-3.2$ git add dev
sh-3.2$ git commit -m 'add file named dev'
[master ac01ba6] add file named dev
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 dev
sh-3.2$ git remote add origin .
sh-3.2$ git update-ref refs/remotes/origin/master master
sh-3.2$ git update-ref refs/remotes/origin/dev master
sh-3.2$ echo foo >> dev
sh-3.2$ git checkout dev
```

Nothing seems to have happened here, but actually, something did: the file `dev` was checked out, destructively.  Here are its contents:

```
sh-3.2$ cat dev
this is a file named dev
```

and here is the confirmation that we are still on `master`:

```
sh-3.2$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

The `working tree clean` is a consequence of destroying the updated `dev`, replacing it with the copy extracted from the index by `git checkout`.

Note that all of this requires a slightly older version of Git:

```
sh-3.2$ git --version
git version 2.20.1
```

A more modern one tells us about the problem.  Doing the same thing in Git 2.24 produces:

```
$ git checkout dev
fatal: 'dev' could be both a local file and a tracking branch.
Please use -- (and optionally --no-guess) to disambiguate
```

This sort of thing is the reason `git checkout` is now two separate commands, `git switch` and `git restore`.  Using `git switch`:

```
$ git switch dev
M       dev
Branch 'dev' set up to track remote branch 'dev' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'dev'
```

does the desired thing.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you haven't fetched the remote branch. By default, git checkout only gets one branch. You need to do a combination of

> git fetch

followed by

> git checkout dev

After that, you should see a message of

> Switched to branch 'dev'
>
> Your branch is up to date with 'origin/dev'

Comment: @hiddeninghewifi - I ran git fetch and then git checkout dev and nothing happens.  That is why I am confused.

Originally I ran 

git clone <location-of-the-repository>

and that sets me at master.  I run:

git fetch

and nothing seems to happen.  Then git checkout dev and it doesn't switch.  I have to be missing something.

Comment: I used (without brackets {}): { git branch -r | grep -v '\->' | while read remote; do git branch --track "${remote#origin/}" "$remote"; done } and that seemed to work.  I have no idea why.  Can someone explain?

Answer (score -1):

You can try below command and see if it works
"git clone --branch  url" 
It is fetching all the branches and checking out to the branch we specify one.